# Why am I getting an OPTIONS request when I enabled CORS in Web API?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, cors

I have a project with Angular Framework and Asp.net Core.

In my ConfigureServices I have bellow code:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(
                    "CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

And un Configure as follow:

```
 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
 app.UseMvc();
```

And after that added EnbaleCors attribute in *BaseApiController*

```
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
public class BaseApiController : Controller
```

In Angular added follow:

```
return this.http
        .post(url, body, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return response as any;
        })
```

When I run the application I have 2 requests in Network, One of them Request Method: OPTIONS with Status Code: 204 No Content and other in my request.

Where is my problem?

Thanks for taking the time and share your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem and there is no need to worry.

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts. For example, `XMLHttpRequest` and the
>   Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web
>   application using those APIs can only request HTTP resources from the
>   same origin the application was loaded from, unless the response from
>   the other origin includes the right CORS headers.

The `OPTIONS` request is merely a security check for safe network calls between cross origins. Hence, when you make such a request, the client will send an `OPTIONS` request to same address to ensure that it is safe to send the original request(`GET`/`POST`).

Comment: @arcreezy Thanks, Can I disable or hide this OPTIONS request in production?

Comment: @SaeidMirzaei I don't think you can't disable client from sending CORS request if client and server are in different domains. There might be a workaround by changing **Content-Type** of your requests to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain` but i wouldn't encourage it.

Comment: I don't have any different domains, I have two subdomains like 'api.my-doamin.com' and 'client.my-doamin.com'. Is it ok in this situation?

Comment: @SaeidMirzaei What i meant with different domains are your client and server and not the URLs. As I told, it won't cause any issue whatsoever.